# Increasing SSL handshaking performance

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I've got a short-lived client process that talks to a server over SSL.  The process is invoked frequently and only runs for a short time (typically for less than 1 second).  This process is intended to be used as part of a shell script used to perform larger tasks and may be invoked pretty frequently.

The SSL handshaking it performs each time it starts up is showing up as a significant performance bottleneck in my tests and I'd like to reduce this if possible.

One thing that comes to mind is taking the session id and storing it somewhere (kind of like a cookie), and then re-using this on the next invocation, however this is making me feel uneasy as I think there would be some security concerns around doing this.

So, I've got a couple of questions,

1. Is this a bad idea?
2. Is this even possible using OpenSSL?
3. Are there any better ways to speed up the SSL handshaking process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the handshake, you can get the SSL session information from your connection with `SSL_get_session()`.  You can then use `i2d_SSL_SESSION()` to serialise it into a form that can be written to disk.

When you next want to connect to the same server, you can load the session information from disk, then unserialise it with `d2i_SSL_SESSION()` and use `SSL_set_session()` to set it (prior to `SSL_connect()`).

The on-disk SSL session should be readable only by the user that the tool runs as, and stale sessions should be overwritten and removed frequently.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a session cache securely (which OpenSSL supports), see the documentation on [SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode.html), [SSL_set_session](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_set_session.html#) and [SSL_session_reused](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_session_reused.html) for more information on how this is achieved.

Answer (score 2):

Could you perhaps use a persistent connection, so the setup is a one-time cost?

You could abstract away the connection logic so your client code still *thinks* its doing a connect/process/disconnect cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly enough I encountered an issue with OpenSSL handshakes just today. The implementation of RAND_poll, on Windows, uses the Windows heap APIs as a source of random entropy.

Unfortunately, due to a "bug fix" in Windows 7 (and Server 2008) the heap enumeration APIs (which are debugging APIs afterall) now can take over a second per call once the heap is full of allocations. Which means that both SSL connects and accepts can take anywhere from 1 seconds to more than a few minutes.

[The Ticket](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=2100&user=guest&pass=guest) contains some good suggestions on how to patch openssl to achieve far FAR faster handshakes.